# Is it possible to run Native C++ code in Windows Azure?

Tags: c++, azure, unmanaged, cloud

I have an application written in native C++ which intends intensive computation. In fact I'm interested only in result of computation, i.e. it can be done without GUI or be controlled by some .Net service/application.

Can I run it in Microsoft's Cloud? How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean stuff like P/Invoke, it is definitely possible!

You have to configure your worker role to `enableNativeCodeExecution` though, but that's fair, don't you think? ;)

You can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/03/18/calling-into-native-dlls-on-windows-azure.aspx).

Comment: Great! As far as I understood, I can build my dll for x64 under Windows using my favourite compiler (for example, ICC),OpenMP, IPP  and then call it from .Net code inside cloud. Am I correct?
Is it possible to use threading and semaphores and so on inside native code?

Comment: Well, I found that it's all possible. `mookid`, great thanks!